# Python: Overlapping boxes around motion detected

Tags: python, opencv, overlapping, motion-detection

I am currently doing a motion detection project that detects motion and draws a red bounding box around motion. Right now my program do detect motion and draw a bounding box around motion, but there is also a lot of overlapping bounding box along with the correct bounding box. Is there a way i can reduce to just 1 box?

This is my code:

```
    for c in cnts:
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < 500:
            continue

        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

This is the current result (found this picture online but it is the same problem):
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the current output with overlapped boxes and expected image with single box as well ?

Comment: @ZdaR I have edited the question to show the current output. The expected output would be just 1 bounding box around the motion

Comment: you could use a simple algorithm like, do boxes overlap? if yes choose larger of two boxes.

Comment: @Aplin, why did you remove the code and image from your question? That makes it harder for anyone to answer your question. Viewing the edit version with your code and the example error output, I believe my answer covers what you want. If this is not the case, then please clarify in your question.

Comment: There are multiple ways to "reduce to just 1 box". If the current answer does not satisfy your specific want, then you need to clarify *exactly* what you want. In addition, taking that example image and editing it to show the desired output would greatly assist those who seek to answer you.

Answer (score 1):

To display only one bounding box in your end result you will have to save the raw image first. Then every time you draw the bounding box, you will have to draw it on a copy of the original raw image and save this new drawn-on image as your result.

I am assuming that you are using a loop and inside this loop you draw the bounding box on the image, but keep drawing over the same image variable each time, thus resulting in multiple visible bounding boxes. If this is an incorrect assumption, then please clarify in your question, provide more of your code, and provide a current example of your output with the error visible, as well as an example of the desired result.

If you just want the most recent box depicting motion you do not need to worry about the algorithms below.

## groupRectangles()

There exists a built-in function in openCV that groups rectangles that are near each other and of similar shape and size called [groupRectangles()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#grouprectangles). It will return a list of rectangles resulting from the combined rectangles that are near each other. There should be a similar, if not exactly the same function for different versions of openCV ([3.0 beta docs of groupRectangles()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=grouprectangles#cv2.groupRectangles)).

## Simple to write algorithms:

As [hinted by @pypypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299447/python-overlapping-boxes-around-motion-detected/45356574#comment-77561288) in a comment to your question, if the redrawn box is too small and does not show your desired area of motion, then you can do a simple algorithm to combine them. However, taking the larger of the two boxes may not be what you desire due to small movements not being depicted by the bounding box (you need to clarify your desired output with an example).

There is a simple algorithm for combining the bounding boxes so that you will have a bounding box that covers the total area of the new bounding box and the previous one. This algorithm involves taking the max and min of all x and y values from both boxes and then *only* drawing the new box based on those x and y values onto a copy of the original raw image. This will create a bounding box the encapsulates all current and previous area of motion.

Comment: i have edited back my question to show you more of my code and also added my current output of my codes

Comment: @Aplin It appears that my answer answers your question. In your for loop you call rectangle on frame only and repeatedly. This is why you have all of those bounding boxes. You could save the tuples as Rect objects from boundingRect into a list, then after the loop call groupRectangles passing it the list. Then loop through its output drawing the resulting bounding boxes. This will allow you to detect multiple areas of movement but without overlapping boxes. Or you could find the min & max of all corners of the boxes and create & draw a new single box from that. Isn't this the solution?